# Does Whatsapp store my friends Whatsapp version locally on my device database?

Tags: android, database, whatsapp

I wanted to know whether Whatsapp store certain info like device version of my friends or any other Whatsapp user i'm trying to contact. The question came to my mind when I upgraded my app and tried to video call my friend and it said that opposite user has not updated the app and gets cancelled. So, is there something to do with the database i.e Are their details stored locally on my device for faster response ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that when trying to connect the call, WhatsApp validated that the person you were trying to connect to did not have the update, but probably after trying to connect to the destination phone.

I do not think that WhatsApp stores your contact information locally, more than profile photos.

Comment: Yes that is what i wanted to know, that if not storing locally then does it use api ?